# Java Code to run Mac Terminal command to Tweak JVM memory

Tags: java, jvm

I am developing a Application using JavaFx 2.2.3 and jdk 1.7.0_09.This application will run on Windows, and Mac Osx.
The problem is I am getting Out-Of-Memory.
I know -Xms and -Xmx are used to tweak JVM memory. But requirement is we have to set JVM memory using java code as This is a desktop application so we can't tweak JVM on every system.

Now I find a solution for windows

proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c java -Xms250m -Xmx1024m -jar \"application.jar\" /n");

By using this code i can increase JVM memory before starting my Application jar.
But this is a solution for Windows only.

Can any one tell similar kind of code For Mac.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to find where java is installed. This document from Apple explains how to do that - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1170/_index.html

String JAVA=...

proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(JAVA+ " -Xms250m -Xmx1024m -jar "application.jar");

So let's assume Java is at '/usr/bin/java', then:

proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/java -Xms250m -Xmx1024m -jar application.jar");

Note that if you need to capture output from 'proc' then you can do something like this:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(proc.getInputStream());
while ((ls_str = ls_in.readLine()) != null) {
  // Do something with the output from proc
  System.out.println(ls_str);
}
```

Comment: I has tried this but no success. I also Tried these bellow but no success                            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Terminal java -Xms250m -Xmx1024m -jar \"Application.jar\" /n");

proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Xms250m -Xmx1024m -jar \"Application.jar\" /n");

proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal java -Xms250m -Xmx1024m -jar \"Application.jar\" /n");

Comment: It is Working if I donot have any space in between folder path of the application.jar

Comment: You need to escape the spaces. Can you give an example of the folder path you're trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase memory for the already running JVM. The standard way is providing start scripts that add the JVM parameters. Or if you use webstart, I think the heap size can be configured in the jnlp file.

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, he's not trying to increase the memory of the running JVM. He's launching another JVM from within a running JVM - so that will fork a separate process.

Comment: yes if im using Jnlp or web-start every thing works fine but the application is a desktop-application and we need to create installer for both OS there we have to only use Jar file.

Comment: If you start a new JVM anyway, why not just pass the correct values for Xmx? How do you start the new JVM?

Comment: yes if im using Jnlp or web-start every thing works fine but the application is a desktop-application and we need to create installer for both OS there we have to only use Jar file.Because of this i created a different jar which checks whats the heap size and execute commands to increase JVM memory then run the actual Jar. So I think if we run a command like Java -Xms250m -Xmx1024m -jar Application.jar with java code for windows something must be for Mac as well.

Comment: I don't know how you installer works, but shouldn't it be possible to create a desktop shortcut on windows that points to the java executable and fills in all the necessary startup parameters? The same should be possible with very little work on mac (but I don't have one here, so I cannot try it).